# What is the name of the maximum training level setting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Does anyone know the console command to change the default setting for the maximum amount of training levels in Oblivion?
I'm attempting to alter it, and the `setgs` console command works, but using the setting `iTrainingNumAllowedPerLevel` (the setting's name in Skyrim) does not. I know it exists, because I've used it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the value is called `ITrainingSkills`, as said in [this discussion on UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion_talk:Trainers#Mod_to_remove_the_5_trains_per_level_limit.3F).

From [the NexusMods Forum](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/44552-realistic-leveling/page-12#entry587960) it seems the command to change it, is:

```
setgamesetting itrainingskills, (number)
```

Comment: This seems to come closer to what my interpretation of the question was as well. Can you actually change those settings in-game? The thread you linked is not conclusive about that.

Comment: @Joachim - I dunno. I don't have my copy installed. Know anyone who can test for us?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is correct, and worked perfectly. (Edit~ To be exact, the comma in the command isn't necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the values of your player character's skills using  `modpcs` (**mod**ify **p**layer **c**haracter **s**kill), and change their attributes using `modpca` (**mod**ify **p**layer **c**haracter **a**ttribute).

They are used like this:

- `modpcs <SkillName (without spaces)> <value (0 to max. 255)>` (e.g. `modpcs sneak 120`)
- `modpcs <AttributeName> <value (0 to max. 255)>` (e.g. `modpca intelligence 80`)

The alternative is using `player.setav <attribute> <n>`, which works for both attributes and skills.

The difference between the two approaches is how they are taken into account when leveling up your player character: `setav` counts directly towards levels (increasing a skill this way will advance your level like a 'natural' increase would do), whereas `modpc` will "*technically give you negative progress towards your next skill increase*".

---

I read your question as asking for a way to allow the game to keep leveling up your PC after the vanilla limits (of 100) were reached - tweaking the ceiling, so to speak, without changing the actual values. So, just to be clear, these commands don't only *change* the maximum level allowed, but will *set* it to the given value.
For targeting skills (and attributes) specifically however, they seem to be the best option you have (as using `advlevel`, `setlevel <n>`, or `advskill <skill> <n>` has more serious drawbacks).

<sup>[Source](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Cheats_(Oblivion)#Skills_and_attributes) of quote - more info [here](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Console).</sup>

Comment: I was looking to increase the number of skill training sessions per level allowed, beyond the set limit of 5. The command to do so is "setgs [game setting] [new limit]", but I didn't know what the specific game setting was called. It's been answered now, but thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem! Yeah, I know, I realized when I read the other answer, and was curious to know if a command like that would work in-game. Glad to know it does!